# Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am trying to install a library from the source that makes use of Poetry, but I get this error

```
error: Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout: ['tulips', 'fixtures'].
        
To avoid accidental inclusion of unwanted files or directories,
setuptools will not proceed with this build.
        
If you are trying to create a single distribution with multiple packages
on purpose, you should not rely on automatic discovery.
Instead, consider the following options:
        
1. set up custom discovery (`find` directive with `include` or `exclude`)
2. use a `src-layout`
3. explicitly set `py_modules` or `packages` with a list of names
        
To find more information, look for "package discovery" on setuptools docs
```

What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: What does you directory structure look like?

Comment: @alexpdev I am trying to use this library directly, from the GitHub tar.gz https://github.com/woocart/tulips

Comment: Then you should put the library in your `site-packages` directory or wherever you store your other packages

Comment: `tulip` seems to be c++ library with python bindings, but it's not configured in a right way, as it seems, look [here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3197)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Based on [this comment on a GitHub issue](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3197#issuecomment-1078770109), adding the following lines to your `pyproject.toml` might solve your problem:

```
[tool.setuptools]
py-modules = []
```

(For my case, the other workaround provided in that comment, i.e. adding `py_modules=[]` as a keyword argument to the setup() function in `setup.py`  worked)

Comment: The error message even says "3. explicitly set `py_modules` or `packages` with a list of names".  In my case specifying `packages = ["my_pkg_name"]` under `[tool.setuptools]` in `pyproject.toml` was the solution (I had another directory at the same level that confused `setuptools`).

Comment: Note that this is an error message that presumably started appearing in setuptools version 61.0.0 (https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#v61-0-0) in March 2022. Ubuntu 20.04 comes with version 45.2.0 installed, and it seems 22.04 comes with 59.6.0, so this is error will start showing up more often in the future. Also, just to clarify, the workaround requires that `py_modules=[]` be added as a *keyword argument* to the `setup()` function.

Comment: You'd think that if one of the "confusing" options is the package name, it's not *that* confusing...

Comment: `py-modules = []` *seemed* to work for me, but turned out not to inlude my Python files (metadata only).  Replacing it with `packages = ["<package name>"]` seems to fare better.

Comment: had to down vote this one,  so rather than py-modules, I would use the same table with packages. If you intend to build all those packages or as it were directories, enter multiple strings into packages, but if it is only one, then enter just the one, still using an array. If you try other configurations as explained here https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html things will fail down the line.

Answer (score 8):

Adding the following in `pyproject.toml` worked for me. It was a repo with many folders but just one folder had the package code:

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]  # list of folders that contain the packages (["."] by default)
include = ["<package name>"]  # package names should match these glob patterns (["*"] by default)
exclude = []  # exclude packages matching these glob patterns (empty by default)
namespaces = false  # to disable scanning PEP 420 namespaces (true by default)
```

Comment: makes sense, so one has to refer to the TOML docs with their configuration in mind to find help i.e. "what am I doing and what can I do to make it pass".