# Multiple Top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout:['share','resource'].Ros2-galactic installation,colcon build error

Tags: python, setuptools, ubuntu-20.04, ros2, colcon

I'm trying to install Ros2-galactic in Ubuntu 20.04 version.
while Installing I'm facing the following issue.

```
--- stderr: rqt                                                                                                                                 
error: Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout: ['share', 'resource'].

To avoid accidental inclusion of unwanted files or directories,
setuptools will not proceed with this build.

If you are trying to create a single distribution with multiple packages
on purpose, you should not rely on automatic discovery.
Instead, consider the following options:

1. set up custom discovery (`find` directive with `include` or `exclude`)
2. use a `src-layout`
3. explicitly set `py_modules` or `packages` with a list of names

To find more information, look for "package discovery" on setuptools docs.
---
Failed   <<< rqt [11.6s, exited with code 1]
Aborted  <<< rqt_publisher [5.17s]                                                                                                           
Aborted  <<< rqt_graph [11.8s]                                                                                         
Aborted  <<< rviz_default_plugins [21min 4s]                                              

Summary: 305 packages finished [26min 55s]
  1 package failed: rqt
  3 packages aborted: rqt_graph rqt_publisher rviz_default_plugins
  76 packages had stderr output: action_tutorials_py ament_clang_format ament_clang_tidy ament_copyright ament_cppcheck ament_cpplint ament_flake8 ament_index_python ament_lint ament_lint_cmake ament_mypy ament_package ament_pclint ament_pep257 ament_pycodestyle ament_pyflakes ament_uncrustify ament_xmllint demo_nodes_py domain_coordinator examples_rclpy_executors examples_rclpy_guard_conditions examples_rclpy_minimal_action_client examples_rclpy_minimal_action_server examples_rclpy_minimal_client examples_rclpy_minimal_publisher examples_rclpy_minimal_service examples_rclpy_minimal_subscriber examples_rclpy_pointcloud_publisher examples_tf2_py joystick_ros2 launch launch_ros launch_testing launch_testing_ros launch_xml launch_yaml osrf_pycommon quality_of_service_demo_py ros2action ros2bag ros2cli ros2component ros2doctor ros2interface ros2launch ros2lifecycle ros2multicast ros2node ros2param ros2pkg ros2run ros2service ros2test ros2topic ros2trace rosidl_cli rosidl_runtime_py rpyutils rqt rqt_bag rqt_console rqt_graph rqt_gui rqt_gui_py rqt_msg rqt_plot rviz_default_plugins sensor_msgs_py sros2 tf2_ros_py tf2_tools topic_monitor tracetools_launch tracetools_read tracetools_trace
  23 packages not processed
```

I've seen similar type of errors and their solutions,from the following link
"[Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72294299/multiple-top-level-packages-discovered-in-a-flat-layout)" But unable to slove it.
I couldn't find the setuptools in my system to edit the **pyproject.toml** file and aslo **setup.py** file.
*where can I find those files in unbuntu version 20.04,
In the system various versions of python is also there*